# Read command is parsing multiline input

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, newline, ifs

The `read` command in the below code is parsing only the first line from the input. But it works fine when the `IFS` is set to comma or any other symbol other than newline.

```
u="*
john
dan"

IFS=$'\n';read -ra q <<< "$u"

for j in "${q[@]}"
do
    echo "drop user $j"
done
```

The output is just:

```
drop user *
```

What I'm expecting is:

```
drop user *
drop user john
drop user dan
```

Note that the first item in the input is an asterisk. So if I use the below code for splitting, then the asterisk gets expanded to the list of files in the directory.

```
IFS=$'\n'; q=($u); unset IFS;
```

Output:

```
drop user abc
drop user test.sh
drop user john
drop user dan
```

What is wrong with the above code? How to correct it to get the intended output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do this `while read` loop:

```
u="*
john
dan"
while IFS= read -r user; do
    echo "drop user $user"
done <<< "$u"
```

**Output:**

```
drop user *
drop user john
drop user dan
```

Answer (score 3):

`read` reads just a single line from standard input. If you have Bash 4.0 or newer, you can use `readarray`:

```
readarray -t q <<< "$u"
```

after which your array looks like this:

```
$ declare -p q
declare -a q=([0]="*" [1]="john" [2]="dan")
```

`readarray` (and its alias `mapfile`) defaults to delimiting array elements with newlines, so the `IFS` assignment can be dropped. Bash 4.4 introduced a `-d` option to use a delimiter other than newline, but that's not required here.

Once your elements are in an array, you can print your commands with a single `printf` statement as follows:

```
printf 'drop user %s\n' "${q[@]}"
```